# How to exchange an authorization token on the server side

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got an ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web API, using OAuth authentication. In addition, we are using claims-based authentication, with the claims encoded in the auth token.

This has been working well for a while, but lately things have gotten out of hand when a new requirement came up that radically multiplied the number of claims that had to be stored in the token. To cut a long story short, we're now at the point where the auth token is so long that we had to reconfigure our server to allow headers over 128k.

This is obviously untenable; just from the perspective of network traffic it's absurd to have to send over 100k of headers along with the simplest GET request. So now I'm thinking along the following lines: instead of encoding the claims in the token, just use a Guid token and store the claims in the *database* along with the token, so when we validate the token we can pull out the claims at the same time and exchange those locally.

Theoretically this should solve our entire problem in one fell swoop, but I'm just stuck on the implementation details, specifically: since the claim-based authentication is expecting to find the claims encoded in the auth token, how do I swap out the Guid auth token for the one that includes all the claims?

Existing code:

```
public class MyAuthenticationEvents : OAuthValidationEvents
{
    public override async Task ValidateToken(ValidateTokenContext context)
    {
        if (context.Properties.ExpiresUtc < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            context.Fail("Access Token has expired.");
            return;
        }
        if (!await TokenIsValidAsync(context)) // code to validate the auth token against the database, could be modified to return claims
        {
            context.Fail("Access Token has not been properly set or has been invalidated.");
            return;
        }
        // Here I would expect to do some skullduggery to switch the compact Guid token for a large token containing claims
        context.Success();
    }
}
```

What's the correct syntax? Or am I barking up the wrong tree, and there's an entirely better way of achieving my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty simple. All I needed to do in the `ValidateToken()` method was to create a new `ClaimsPrincipal` using a `ClaimsIdentity` which I reconstructed based on the serialized claims that I stored on the database:

```
  ... // create claimsIdentity from serialized claims
  context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
  context.Success();
}
```

Just one thing to take note of: on the initial login, it is mandatory to return a `Subject` claim, so in the `HandleTokenRequest()` method we still need:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, user.Username));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your existing authentication middleware is populating claims on a `ClaimsPrincipal` based on the contents of the JWT, but by the time your authorization handlers inspect the claims they're not read directly from the token, so there's no need to modify the token itself.

You should be able to access and modify the current user (`HttpContext.User`) claims from middleware, so you can make [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#write-middleware) that executes after the authentication middleware and adds claims based on the results of the database lookup.

Edit: As Shaul points out in his answer, this can also be done in the `Validate` method of your authentication components. That's actually a good place to do it in this case. Separate middleware (as I described) would work if you wanted the 'translation' of claims to those from a database to be decoupled from the auth process. The key point is that ASP.NET Core stores user claims in `ClaimsPrincipal` objects and you just need to update that rather than worrying about the token itself.